# Qt addwidget from function

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

For first I'm newbie in Qt and I need some advice about add widgets. I created simple code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::AddButtons()
{
  qDebug() << "click";
  QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(this);
  ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(button);
}

void MainWindow::on_blablaButton_clicked()
{
  QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(this);
  ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(button);
}
```

So on_blablaButton_clicked() - I created from Design and this works as expected.

AddButtons() - public void function, I call from another widget. And in this case, addWidget(button) doesn't work. But button click work, I see debug message in the log.

As I understand I can't create widget from custom function, that's right? And for this operation, I need to use another method?

UPD:

So I add more debug messages and I find something weird.

My upd code:

```
void MainWindow::AddButtons()
{
qDebug() << "click";
QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(this);
qDebug() << "button name" << button;
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(button);
qDebug() << "layout count" << ui->verticalLayout->count();
button->show();
qDebug() << "post click";
}

void MainWindow::on_blablaButton_clicked()
{
QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(this);
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(button);
qDebug() << "layout count" << ui->verticalLayout->count();
}
```

And I get this in my log when click my custom funct:

```
click

button name QPushButton(0x2a10a17de10)

layout count 1

post click

click

button name QPushButton(0x2a10a17f4d0)

layout count 1

post click
```

And if push thus button (::on_blablaButton_clicked())

```
layout count 1

layout count 2

layout count 3
```

I can't understand why my layout count is different??? I think I did something wrong... but for now, can't find what.

UPD2:

With your help, I got this. So qcast - some reason didn't help me (I need to more information about this cast I think). But if I directly add pointer link (with MainWindow) to my widget that's works perfect!

This is how it's look in mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Form* f = new Form;
    f->Parent = this;
    layout()->addWidget(f);

}
```

and in my custom widget...

```
void Form::on_customWidgetButton_clicked()
{
    //MainWindow* m = new MainWindow();
    //m->AddButtons();

    //MainWindow* m = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parentWidget());

    Parent->AddButtons();
}
```

As you see I failed with qobject_cast... That's strange because some part of code works fine and stack in this line... (maybe for someone this makes sense):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBxf3.png)

UPD3:

Ok. Cast works too. Now I got the real problem - this method doesn't work with "promoted" widget some reason. So, how I created my widget in first time - I created form.ui file, changed it and promoted empty widget in mainwindow.ui to my custom widget class. In this way I can't add new button in layout (see debug image).

But if I add widget in this way:

```
Form* f = new Form;
f->Parent = this;
layout()->addWidget(f);
```

All works perfectly.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. You can create widgets as you want. Nothing is forbidden. What you mean by "addWidget(button) doesn't work"? Doesn't compile, doesn't do what your expect, other?

Comment: What happened if you call `button->show();` after `ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(button);` in `AddButtons()` function?

Comment: How did you call `AddButtons()` from another widget?
there are some signal/slot relation?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov All compiled well. I mean when I click this button I can see my debug message, but I can't see a new widget in layout.

Comment: @Peter Nothing. Same issue.

Comment: @Jin  
    MainWindow* m = new MainWindow();
    m->AddButtons();
But as I said this part works fine (I get my debug message).

Comment: What is size of you buttons? Are they visible?

Comment: You should verify if there is already another instance of MainWindow created before. And the newly created MainWindow is just behind the old one :) The code `MainWindow * m = new MainWindow();  m->AddButtons(); m->show();` works for me.

Comment: You create the buttons. But you don't free them. That's why layout count is different with every click.

Comment: @TungLeThanh Mmmm. I get it! Thanks for an answer) But this method created a new window, I need to add widget in old one. So, I try to cast parent widget like this - MainWindow* casted = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parentWidget());
    casted->AddButtons();

But project crash when I tried to add button in layout...

Comment: @SergeyKozin: so the qobject_cast failed because your parentWidget is not MainWindow type. A way to do that is to pass directly the MainWindow pointer to your work (child) widget.

Comment: See your updated question, it seems that you call to AddButtons to differents MainWindow instances each time, so that layout count is always 1, add a `<< this` to see if the pointer changed in each call.

Comment: Guys thank you all for answers! That's was very helpful! I updated the answer with worked code)

Comment: `f->Parent = this;` Is this legal now or a bug?